# How to disable fields initialization in constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, malloc

Is it possible to disable fields initialization in constructor? I don't want constructor of my class to call constructors of fields of this class, how can I do it without using malloc? I'd like to do it to avoid double initialization in code like that:

```
class A() {
   A(int n): N(n) {}
}

class B() : public A() {
    B(int n) : A(n) {}
    B() {
        new(this) B(42);
    }
}
```

Comment: Make them pointers or wrap them in boost::optional (boost::optional will still be called tho .. )

Comment: Still going to want to set them pointers to null tho.

Comment: and without making pointers? no way?

Comment: @Fippo depends on what the members are. Are they PODs?

Comment: do you want to disable **initialization** or do you want to disable **constructor calls**? those are two different things. the former is easily achieved for POD types, the latter is fairly impossible. anyway, this does sound as a novice's **premature optimization**.

Comment: How about implementing a generic `lazy<T>`?

Comment: I want to disable constructor call's, you are correct.

Comment: @Fippo you just want to set A::N to 42 if B default constructor `B()` is called?

Comment: no, it's just an example. I'd like have the constructor that can't initialize object and just run another constructor.

Comment: so, it's just not possible?

Comment: This sounds like either trying to optimise something that isn't an optimisation (the compiler will optimise it for you if it's not needed), or an XY question, where you are asking about Y, because you want to achieve X. If you are wanting to do X, then explain that, and we can probably help you find an answer. Also, it would help to understand what N is. Where does it come from [it's not in your code-snippet, so as such this code doesn't compile!]

Comment: replace B(int n) : A(n) {} with  B(int n=42) : A(n) {} and get rid of the B()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put: you can't. Constuctors of members are called always. And it's good, because an object isn't constructed if viable parts of it are missing. With viable I mean opposed to optional. Optional in C++ should be expressed by either pointers or `boost::optional` as suggested in the comments.

Furthermore it's a language crime if you call placement new on this inside a constructor, because you initialize an object a second time. Simply said, you are messing with object lifetimes here what is dubious, error prone and hard to understand and maintain at best.

What you are looking for is simply not possible in C++03. What is possible in C++11, however, are so-called *delegating constructors*, which maybe are what you are looking for:

```
class B() : public A() {
    B(int n) : A(n) {}
    B() : B(42) //delegate the default ctor to the int ctor
    { /* do more stuff*/ } 
}
```

However, you can't do *everything* with them - you can just call another constructor of the same class.

Answer (score 1):

I feel I understand your question, you want `Delegating Constructors`, but this is only available in C++11

```
class Notes {
  int k;
  double x;
  std::string st;
public:
  Notes();
  Notes(int);
  Notes(int, double);
  Notes(int, double, std::string);
};

Notes::Notes(int kk, double xx, std::string stt) : k(kk),
  x(xx), st(stt) {/*do stuff*/}
Notes::Notes() : Notes(0, 0.01, "Oh") {/* do other stuff*/}
Notes::Notes(int kk) : Notes(kk, 0.01, "Ah") {/* do yet other stuff*/ }
Notes::Notes( int kk, double xx ) : Notes(kk, xx, "Uh") {/* ditto*/ }
```